# restoreCompletedTransactions method return all user subscribed transations or not

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am doing one application. In that I am using `In-App Purchase` auto renewal subscription. So here my doubt is when the user calls the `restoreCompletedTransactions` method, it will return user subscribed transaction details under this application or under all application. Because user will use same apple id for all application to subscribe. So apple will return all transactions or only transactions belongs to present application.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in-App purchases includes `bundle identifier` and `product identifier` to `make a payment` and its unique throughout out, So you will get only the transaction that belongs to particular app. Have a look at the example purchases setup [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).